# Facebook SDK - check permissions correctly on startup

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I have app using Facebook SDK and permissions to access user's data.

How can I correctly check these situations:

- user has logged off the Facebook account in iPhone settings
- user has logged off the Facebook account and logged in using another account in iPhone settings
- user has denied the app to access the Facebook account in iPhone settings

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I am able to check, if the user is not logged in into Facebook on iPhone setting. But I'm not able to check, if the user has logged out in FB app

**UPDATE**

There is no need to check, if the user has logged out from Facebook app. All what I need is to check if the user has changed the phone settings by observing `ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the iOS documentation here:
[Apple Documentation on ACAccountStore](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ACAccountStore/requestAccessToAccountsWithType%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a)

You'll find whatever is needed to ask user permissions and check current auth status on iOS6.